# Need help approximating sine function in python using Taylor Series

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python, and am trying to approximate the sine function using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJOya.png) series.

My code looks like this:

```
import math
def sin(x,n):
sine = 0
for i in range(n):
    sign = (-1)**i
    sine = sine + ((x**(2.0*i-1))/factorial(2**i-1))*sign
return sine
```

This does not return the answer that I was hoping for, but I am very confused and can't find my mistake... or maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way entirely (as I said, I'm very new to python and to programming in general).

It seems similar to the program that I had to write a while ago to approximate pi given [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfUio.png) series:

```
def piApprox(n):
pi = 0
for i in range(n):
    sign = (-1)**i
    pi = pi + 1.0/(2*i+1)*sign
return 4*pi
```

I don't know if that is useful in any way, but it's what I was trying to use that to figure out my sine method.  Any help fixing this or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does its behaviour differ from what you expected, specifically?

Comment: I was expecting it to return an answer close to what math.sin(x) would return. I feel like my problem lies somewhere within the for i in range(n): portion of the code.

Comment: Ok, then you should pick a simple example input, modify your code to print out all the intermediate results, and compare them to a manual calculation.

Answer (score 5):

The Taylor series for sin(*x*) is:

[image: Taylor series for sin(x)]

Comparing your code to that definition, these two parts have some errors:

```
x**(2.0*i-1)
factorial(2**i-1)
```

The minuses should be pluses, and the exponent in the factorial should be multiplication.

```
x**(2.0*i+1)
factorial(2*i+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the symbolic library SymPy to build your approximated function using Taylor series:

```
from sympy import sin
from sympy.abc import x

# creates a generator
taylor_series = sin(x).series(n=None)

# takes the number of terms desired for your generator
taylor_series = sum([next(taylor_series) for i in range(num_of_terms)])

# creates a function that calculates the approximated sine function
mysin = sympy.lambdify((x,), taylor_series)
```