# Computing taylor series of multivariate function with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, taylor-series

I am trying to compute with SymPy the taylor series of a function which depends on the trigonomertic function **sinc**  ([here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/functions/trigonometric.html#sinc-function)), to simplify my problem, we can assume the function I need the Taylor series of is :

```
f(x1, x2) = sinc(x1) * sinc(x2)
```

My problem is that when importing **sympy.mpmath** I often get the error :

> cannot create mpf from ...

I have tried to use the [taylor-series](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/approximation.html#taylor-series-taylor) approximation or [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857162/multivariate-taylor-approximation-in-sympy) (number 1.), but they all seem to fail. For example for the later alternative the line :

```
(sinc(x)*sinc(y)).series(x,0,3).removeO().series(y,0,3).removeO()
```

returns :

> cannot create mpf from x

I also have tried of defining the function as an expression and as a lambda function. But nothing seems to work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use mpmath functions with symbolic SymPy objects. You need to define `sinc` symbolically.

One way is to just define it as a Python function that returns the equivalent (here `sin` is `sympy.sin`):

```
def sinc(x):
    return sin(x)/x
```

Or, you could write your own SymPy class for it.

```
class sinc(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, x):
        if x == 0:
            return 1
        # Should also include oo and -oo here
        sx = sin(x)
        # Return only if sin simplifies
        if not isinstance(sx, sin):
            return sx/x

    # You'd also need to define fdiff or _eval_derivative here so that it knows what the derivative is
```

The latter lets you write `sinc(x)` and it will be printed like that, and you can also define custom behavior with it like what the derivative looks like, how the series works, and so on. This would also let you define the correct values at 0, oo, and so on.

But for the purposes of taking series, just using `sin(x)/x` (i.e., the first solution) works fine, because your final answer won't have `sinc` in it anyway, and the series methods take the limit correctly when evaluating at points like 0.

Comment: There is also an open SymPy issue to implement `sinc` https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5051

Comment: Thanks I was afraid the first solution wouldn't work because of the limit in 0. But it does. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Here is a multivariate Taylor series expansion to be used with Sympy that I just wrote:

```
def Taylor_polynomial_sympy(function_expression, variable_list, evaluation_point, degree):
    """
    Mathematical formulation reference:
    https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Multivariable_Calculus/3%3A_Topics_in_Partial_Derivatives/Taylor__Polynomials_of_Functions_of_Two_Variables
    :param function_expression: Sympy expression of the function
    :param variable_list: list. All variables to be approximated (to be "Taylorized")
    :param evaluation_point: list. Coordinates, where the function will be expressed
    :param degree: int. Total degree of the Taylor polynomial
    :return: Returns a Sympy expression of the Taylor series up to a given degree, of a given multivariate expression, approximated as a multivariate polynomial evaluated at the evaluation_point
    """
    from sympy import factorial, Matrix, prod
    import itertools

    n_var = len(variable_list)
    point_coordinates = [(i, j) for i, j in (zip(variable_list, evaluation_point))]  # list of tuples with variables and their evaluation_point coordinates, to later perform substitution

    deriv_orders = list(itertools.product(range(degree + 1), repeat=n_var))  # list with exponentials of the partial derivatives
    deriv_orders = [deriv_orders[i] for i in range(len(deriv_orders)) if sum(deriv_orders[i]) <= degree]  # Discarding some higher-order terms
    n_terms = len(deriv_orders)
    deriv_orders_as_input = [list(sum(list(zip(variable_list, deriv_orders[i])), ())) for i in range(n_terms)]  # Individual degree of each partial derivative, of each term

    polynomial = 0
    for i in range(n_terms):
        partial_derivatives_at_point = function_expression.diff(*deriv_orders_as_input[i]).subs(point_coordinates)  # e.g. df/(dx*dy**2)
        denominator = prod([factorial(j) for j in deriv_orders[i]])  # e.g. (1! * 2!)
        distances_powered = prod([(Matrix(variable_list) - Matrix(evaluation_point))[j] ** deriv_orders[i][j] for j in range(n_var)])  # e.g. (x-x0)*(y-y0)**2
        polynomial += partial_derivatives_at_point / denominator * distances_powered
    return polynomial
```

And here is the validation for a two-variate problem, following the exercises and answers in: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Multivariable_Calculus/3%3A_Topics_in_Partial_Derivatives/Taylor__Polynomials_of_Functions_of_Two_Variables

```
# Solving the exercises in section 13.7 of https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Multivariable_Calculus/3%3A_Topics_in_Partial_Derivatives/Taylor__Polynomials_of_Functions_of_Two_Variables
from sympy import symbols, sqrt, atan, ln

# Exercise 1
x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')
function_expression = x*sqrt(y)
variable_list = [x,y]
evaluation_point = [1,4]
degree=1
print(Taylor_polynomial_sympy(function_expression, variable_list, evaluation_point, degree))
degree=2
print(Taylor_polynomial_sympy(function_expression, variable_list, evaluation_point, degree))

# Exercise 3
x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')
function_expression = atan(x+2*y)
variable_list = [x,y]
evaluation_point = [1,0]
degree=1
print(Taylor_polynomial_sympy(function_expression, variable_list, evaluation_point, degree))
degree=2
print(Taylor_polynomial_sympy(function_expression, variable_list, evaluation_point, degree))

# Exercise 5
x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')
function_expression = x**2*y + y**2
variable_list = [x,y]
evaluation_point = [1,3]
degree=1
print(Taylor_polynomial_sympy(function_expression, variable_list, evaluation_point, degree))
degree=2
print(Taylor_polynomial_sympy(function_expression, variable_list, evaluation_point, degree))

# Exercise 7
x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')
function_expression = ln(x**2+y**2+1)
variable_list = [x,y]
evaluation_point = [0,0]
degree=1
print(Taylor_polynomial_sympy(function_expression, variable_list, evaluation_point, degree))
degree=2
print(Taylor_polynomial_sympy(function_expression, variable_list, evaluation_point, degree))
```

It can be useful to perform `simplify()` on the result.