# Taylor series in 2 or more variables (sympy)

Tags: sympy, series

I'm sure I've seen it somewhere...

How do I use the series function in sympy to find the Taylor series for some function like
f(x,y) = x^3+xy-2y^2.
Thank you

.

Comment: See [Computing taylor series of multivariate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63850955/12046409)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing taylor series of multivariate function with sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803320/computing-taylor-series-of-multivariate-function-with-sympy)