# Why does my Sympy code calculate the first order Taylor series approximation incorrectly?

Tags: python, sympy, derivative, taylor-series

I have an expression like this

[image: sympy expression]

which is entered into Sympy like this (for the sake of a reproducible example in this question)

```
from sympy import *
expression = Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Float('0.9926375361451395', prec=2), Add(Mul(Float('0.33167082639756074', prec=2), Pow(Symbol('k1'), Float('-0.66666666666666674', prec=2)), Pow(Symbol('n1'), Float('0.66666666666666674', prec=2))), Mul(Float('0.97999999999999998', prec=2), exp(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('mu1'))))), Pow(Add(Mul(Float('0.97999999999999998', prec=2), Symbol('k1'), exp(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('mu1')))), Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('k2')), Mul(Pow(Symbol('n1'), Float('0.66666666666666674', prec=2)), Pow(Mul(Symbol('k1'), exp(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('mu1')))), Float('0.33333333333333331', prec=2)))), Integer(-1))), Pow(Add(Mul(Float('0.97999999999999998', prec=2), Symbol('k0'), exp(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('mu0')))), Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('k1')), Mul(Pow(Symbol('n0'), Float('0.66666666666666674', prec=2)), Pow(Mul(Symbol('k0'), exp(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('mu0')))), Float('0.33333333333333331', prec=2)))), Integer(-1)))
```

Eyeballing this expression, the first order Taylor approximation for any of the variables, e.g. `k1`, around some nonzero value should be nonzero, but this code

```
x = symbol("x")
expression.series(k1, x0 = x, n = 1)
```

just returns `0`. This is a problem because I'm trying to (eventually) calculate a multivariate Taylor series approximation, in a similar vein to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22877011/2766558), and if one of the series expansions mistakenly evaluates to zero, the whole thing breaks down.

Did I code something wrong, or is my basic calculus just THAT bad and this actually evaluates to zero? From the [documentation on `series`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html#series-expansion), I'm *fairly* certain that I'm using it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a bug related to the way the addition operation handles Orders.

This bug applies only if you are calculating the zero order (n=1) of the Taylor series. To avoid it, you can do

```
next(expression.series(k1, x0=x, n=None))
```

which is equivalent to

```
expression.subs(k1, x0=x)
```

Here is a simple description of this bug:

```
from sympy import cos
from sympy.abc import x
cos(x).series(x, x0=1, n=2)
```

Results in

```
cos(1) - (x - 1)*sin(1) + O((x - 1)**2, (x, 1))
```

But

```
cos(x).series(x, x0=1, n=1)
```

Results in `O(x - 1, (x, 1))`, instead of `cos(1) + O(x - 1, (x, 1))`.

This bug results from a bug in Add

```
O(x).subs(x,x-1) + 1
```

Results in `O(x - 1, (x, 1))`, instead of `1 + O(x - 1, (x, 1))`.

Comment: Looks like this bug is fixed in the git master version of SymPy. There, `O(x).subs(x,x-1) + 1` gives `1 + O(x - 1, (x, 1))`, and the series in question gives `O(k₁ - x; k₁ → x)`.