# Trouble with taylor series in python (sympy)

Tags: python, sympy, taylor-series

I'm trying to get the Taylor series for this function
[image]

Which should be similar to this, considering that d is centered or around rs
[image]

However when I try to take the example of [@Saullo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256181/need-help-approximating-sine-function-in-python-using-taylor-series/40733529#40733529) for my problem,
[image]

As you can see the result is eliminating "d" from the series of Taylor, which should not be my goal.

Another additional info about the function in fact is: 
[image]

I'm doing something wrong ??, is there a way to get my result without deleting "d" ??

Any help is appreciated

### The code

> Thank you for your response and interest in helping me, here is my code until nowdays @asmeurer

```
import sympy as sy
#import numpy as np

from sympy import init_printing
init_printing(use_latex=True)

# Define the variable and the function to approximate
z, d, r_s, N_e, r_t, r_s, r_b = sy.symbols('z  d r_s N_e r_t r_s r_b')

# Define W_model
def W_model(r_t=r_t, r_b=r_b, r_s=r_s, z=z):

    s_model = sy.sqrt(pow(r_t, 2) - pow(r_s*sy.sin(z), 2)) - sy.sqrt(pow(r_b, 2) - pow(r_s*sy.sin(z), 2))
    d_model = r_t - r_b

    STEC_approx = N_e * s_model
    VTEC_approx = N_e * d_model

    return STEC_approx/VTEC_approx

f = W_model() 
# printing Standard model
f

# Some considerations for modify Standard model
rb = r_s - d/2
rt = r_s + d/2

f = W_model(r_b=rb, r_t=rt, r_s=r_s, z=z) 
# printing My model
f

## Finding taylor series aproximmation for W_model
num_of_terms = 2
# creates a generator
taylor_series = f.series(x=d, n=None)

# takes the number of terms desired for your generator
taylor_series = sum([next(taylor_series) for i in range(num_of_terms)])
taylor_series
```

Comment: Please paste your code here. It would make it much easier to test if I could copy and paste it.

Comment: Thank you for your response and interest in helping me, I have updated my question with my code until nowday. @asmeurer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your expression is complicated enough that `series` doesn't know that the odd order terms are zero (you get complicated expressions for them, but if you call `simplify()` on them, they go to 0). Consider

```
In [62]: s = f.series(d, n=None)

In [63]: a1 = next(s)

In [64]: a2 = next(s)

In [65]: simplify(a0)
Out[65]:
       rₛ
────────────────
   _____________
  ╱   2    2
╲╱  rₛ ⋅cos (z)

In [66]: simplify(a1)
Out[66]: 0
```

If you print `a0` and `a1` they are both complicated expressions.  In fact, you need to get several terms (up to `a3`) before series gets a term that doesn't cancel to 0:

```
In [73]: simplify(a3)
Out[73]:
      _____________
 2   ╱   2    2        2
d ⋅╲╱  rₛ ⋅cos (z) ⋅sin (z)
───────────────────────────
           3    6
       8⋅rₛ ⋅cos (z)
```

If you do `f.series(d, n=3)`, it gives the expansion up to `d**2` (`n=3` means `+ O(d**3)`). You can simplify the expression quite a bit using

```
collect(expr.removeO(), d, simplify)
```

Internally, when you give series an explicit `n`, it uses the term-by-term generator to get as many terms as it needs to give the proper `O(d**n)` expansion. If you use the generator yourself (`n=None`), you need to do this manually.

In general, the iterator is not guaranteed to give you the next order term. If you want guarantees that you have all the terms, you need to provide an explicit `n`. The `O` term returned by `series` is always correct (meaning all the lower order terms are complete).

Comment: Great explanation, it is now clearer because of the expressions that I could not recognize.

Thanks for your help. @asmeurer